# How to write python INFO logs to the output and DEBUG logs to a file?

Tags: python, logging

I searched multiple similar questions, but I couldn't find an answer.

Here is an example:

```
logging.info("This should show both in a file and the output")
logging.debug("This should show only in a file")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following code with comments:

```
# The root of the hierarchy of loggers is called the root logger
root_logger = logging.getLogger()

# Set the root to the lowest level of interest, otherwise subsequent handlers won't reach these logs
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add a handler to save DEBUG-level logs (and above) to a file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("my_program.log")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
root_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# Add a handler to log INFO-level logs to a stream. By default it is the sys.stderr, which will show in the output.
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root_logger.addHandler(console_handler)

# Write some logs
logging.info("This should show both in a file and the output")
logging.debug("This should show only in a file")
```